# Pointers Question - What does (double*)params mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm having a bit of trouble in understanding this piece of code.

```
double F(double k,void *params){
  double *p=(double *)params;

  return p[0];
}
```

I have only a small notion of pointers from a class, and I understand that in the function his using the pointer *params as an argument. I also understand that he uses double *p to declare the variable. What I can't figure out is what (double *)params do, or how p got turned into a vector.

Comment: This is a cast from `void*` to `double*`. Which is not needed and can be removed (well, some like to add these to demonstrate the intention).

Comment: There is no vector (nor array, as you probably mean) anywhere in evidence.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(double *)params` means "treat `params` as a pointer to `double` instead of a pointer to `void`".  The `(double *)` is a *cast*.

Under most circumstances you cannot copy a pointer value of one type to a pointer variable of a different type (you can't assign a `double *` value to an `int *` variable) without an explicit cast.

The one exception in C is assigning a `void *` value to a different pointer type or vice versa - in this particular case, the cast is unnecessary.  However, C++ does not allow implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types, so in that language the cast is necessary.

Pointers to different types do not have to have the same size and representation; the only rules are

- `char *` and `void *` have the same size and alignment;
- Pointers to qualified types have the same size and alignment as pointers to the unqualified equivalent (e.g., `const int *` and `volatile int *` have the same size and alignment as `int *`);
- Pointers to all `struct` types have the same size and alignment;
- Pointers to all `union` types have the same size and alignment;

Comment: "Treat `params` as" is a bit misleading relative to the semantics as the language specification puts them: *converting* the value of `params` to another type.  The distinction is more pronounced if you consider casts among arithmetic types, where, say, treating a `float` as an `int` doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

`(double *)params` instructs the compiler to think of `params` (which is a void pointer originally - the compiler has no idea what *type* it's pointing to) as a pointer to a double **only while processing this expression**. It's very commonly known as a "C-style cast of one type to another". In this case, we are "casting" `params` from a `void*` type to a `double*` type, since we are storing it in the pointer to double `double *p`.

Without the cast, the compiler will most likely give you a `type mismatch` error/warning, since you would be trying to store the value of a void pointer into a pointer to double.

More specifically, when you have a double pointer, or pointer to anything *except* void, the compiler associates a number with it in order to be able to perform *pointer arithmetic* on it when you write something like `(ptr++)`. For example, when doing `(++ptr)` on a pointer to double, the compiler **knows** how many bytes to go up by, because it knows the size of a double. However, a **void*** has no size associated with it, therefore the compiler can't perform pointer arithmetic on it. So when casting the void pointer to a double pointer using `(double*)params`, you're allowing the compiler to associate the standard size of variables of type `double` with whatever this void pointer is pointing to **only while processing this expression**, for the purposes of storing its value inside an actual pointer to double. After the compiler is done reading this expression, it goes back to thinking `params` is a void pointer, not a double pointer, ie the effect of casting it to a double pointer is not permanent, it's only valid during the processing of this expression by the compiler.

Comment: In C, it's just a "cast" or "typecast".  Only in C++ context does it make any sense to prepend "C-style".  Additionally, your description in terms of thinking of the value in some other terms is misleading.  A cast expression *converts* the value of an operand to a different type.  In this case, it converts a value of type `void *` to type `double *`.

Comment: "convert" is a misleading word to be using here, because one might think it **permanently** becomes a pointer to double. I'm not using "convert" in my explanation for a very good reason - the void pointer becomes a pointer to double **only during the processing of this expression** by the compiler.

Comment: You wouldn't say that writing `(2 * k)` causes the compiler to think of `k` in a different way.  Similarly, the cast to `double *` does not change how the compiler thinks of `params`... the casted value is its own, separate thing.

Comment: "Convert" is *exactly* the word to use here, as it is how the language specification describes the effect of a cast.  And "conversion" is a defined procedure in the language specification, so this word choice is not accidental, nor subject to change without losing meaning.  But do note that I specifically said "converts **the value** of the operand" -- not the operand itself.

Comment: First answered question on stackoverflow and I'm already getting the old dinosaurs on my tail for no apparent reason :)